# extract values from the array according to the Key and values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, excel, react-native

I have a requirement to extract values from the array according to the occupation into different excel sheets.

```
  { age: 22, name: "Jack McDonald", occupation: "Developer" },
  { age: 22, name: "Bridget Williams", occupation: "Developer" },
  { age: 22, name: "Nathan Thomas", occupation: "Developer" },
  { age: 23, name: "Olivia Beck", occupation: "Tester" },
  { age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "Tester" }
  { age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "BA" }
  { age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "IT" }
  { age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "IT" }
```

I want an excel sheet with the name Developer.csv and should only contain Developer items
likewise, I need another excel sheet with the name Tester.csv and should only contain tester items and so on

I am stuck here. please help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is an array you can use **Array.filter** to match all the needed occupations.
Here is a sample code based on the info you provided

```js
const a = [{ age: 22, name: "Jack McDonald", occupation: "Developer" },
{ age: 22, name: "Bridget Williams", occupation: "Developer" },
{ age: 22, name: "Nathan Thomas", occupation: "Developer" },
{ age: 23, name: "Olivia Beck", occupation: "Tester" },
{ age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "Tester" },
{ age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "BA" },
{ age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "IT" },
{ age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "IT" }]


const developers = a.filter(x=>x.occupation === 'Developer')
const testers = a.filter(x=>x.occupation === 'Tester')

console.log(developers)
console.log(testers)
```

Comment: I have 12 different occupations like that and I cannot make 12 variables and also don't know new occupation might add

Answer (score 0):

As I see your problem has 2 parts:

- First you need to know how many `occupation` are without duplicates

```js
const noDupOccup = [...new Set(arr.map(o=>o.occupation))]
```

- Then you need a filtered array for each `occupation`

```js
for (occ on noDupOccup){
  const cvs = arr.filter(o=>o.occupation === occ)
   // save your 'occ'.cvs here with cvs data
}
```